# writing sql trigger with if conditional

Tags: sql, triggers

I need help writing this trigger, the trigger is on the Product table, when hoursLeft = 0 it need to update the table Offer status= 'Expired'. I am new in sql, I will appreciate any help.

So far I have this:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Product_NoUnitsAvailable
 ON dbo.Product
 FOR UPDATE
 AS

 IF
 (SELECT dbo.Product.hoursLeft FROM dbo.Product, inserted i WHERE dbo.Offer.ProductId = i.ProductId) = 0

BEGIN

UPDATE dbo.Offer
SET Status = 'Expired'
WHERE dbo.Offer.Product = Inserted.ProductId

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the query you want is along these lines:

```
UPDATE o
    SET Status = 'Expired'
    FROM dbo.Offer o JOIN
         Inserted i
         ON o.Product = i.Product
    WHERE i.hoursLeft = 0;
```

The explicit `if` statement isn't needed; the `join` takes care of the filtering.

Comment: Gordon, i am testing your solution